# Create XML string using C# XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create an XML string but the expected output is different from this code

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("Employee");
xml.AppendChild(root);

for (int i = 1; i < datacount; i++)
{
    XmlElement child = xml.CreateElement("EmployeeName");
    child.SetAttribute("value", "Name1");
    root.AppendChild(child);
}

string xmlString = xml.OuterXml;
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employee> 
    <EmployeeName>Name1</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeName>Name2</EmployeeName>
</Employee>
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employee>
    <EmployeeName Value = "Name1" />     
    <EmployeeName Value = "Name1" />       
</Employee>
```

Comment: `child.InnerText = "Name1";`

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("Employee");
xml.AppendChild(root);

//Create a new node and add it to the document.
//The text node is the content of the price element.
for (int i = 1; i < datacount; i++)
{
    XmlElement elem = xml.CreateElement("EmployeeName");
    XmlText text = xml.CreateTextNode("Name");
    xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
    xml.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(text);
}
                
string xmlString = xml.OuterXml;
```

or you can use

```
child.InnerText="Name1";
```